# How can I apply a theme for a specific Material UI React component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've built a theme called MyTheme.js like so:

```
export default {
  spacing: Spacing,
  zIndex: zIndex,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  palette: {
    primary1Color: Color.MY_PRIMARY,
    primary2Color: Color.MY_SECONDARY,
    ...
    pickerHeaderColor: Color.MY_PRIMARY
  }
};
```

And use it as such:

```
getChildContext() {
  return {
    muiTheme: ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(MyTheme)
  };
}
```

The above two snippets of code are following the instructions as provided by v0.14.4 here: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

This theming works, but I am having trouble modifying a specific component's "theme". For example, if I want all of my RaisedButton components to have a bold font as opposed to the default normal-styled font, I am having to modify each button individually.

In this file, it shows all editable fields for the theme: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v0.14.4/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js

But I can't seem to do something like the following:

```
export default {
  spacing: Spacing,
  zIndex: zIndex,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  palette: {
    primary1Color: Color.MY_PRIMARY,
    primary2Color: Color.MY_SECONDARY,
    ...
    pickerHeaderColor: Color.MY_PRIMARY
  },
  raisedButton: {
    fontWeight: 700
  }
};
```

How can I modify the theme for a specific component type?